# How to handle odd resolutions in Unet architecture PyTorch

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, hourglass

I'm implementing a U-Net based architecture in PyTorch. At train time, I've patches of size `256x256` which doesn't cause any problem. However at test time, I've full HD images (`1920x1080`). This is causing a problem during skip connections.

Downsampling `1920x1080` 3 times gives `240x135`. If I downsample one more time, the resolution becomes `120x68` which when upsampled gives `240x136`. Now, I cannot concatenate these two feature maps. How can I solve this?

PS: I thought this is a fairly common problem, but I didn't get any solution or even mentioning of this problem anywhere on the web. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried down-sampling with a different factor along each dimension using `torch.nn.MaxPool2d`?  You could use fix `kernel size = (8, 5)` this would give you `240 x 216` then you could pad the array to meet the require size `256 x 256`without distorting the image too much.

Comment: PS : I suggested `Maxpooling`, but could be `AveragePooling`as well.

Comment: No. I can't use that. Actually, I'm benchmarking Partial ConvNet paper for my research. I don't know if I can modify the architecture like that.

Comment: May I ask why you think this would not work ? Or is it simply the fact that it would mean tempering with the architecture. Thanks

Comment: Yes. It's simply about tampering with the architecture. Plus using different max pooling would cause problem during training right?

Comment: If I got your OP right, it would be for the skip connection. You would not be tempering with the architecture itself, your would be adding pre-processing step on the input data before entering the network. Now if your goal is image segmentation, instead of down-sampling you could also try splitting your HD pics into `256 x 256` chunk, this way you don't temper with the resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a very common problem in segmentation networks where skip-connections are often involved in the decoding process. Networks usually (depending on the actual architecture) require input size that has side lengths as integer multiples of the largest stride (8, 16, 32, etc.).

There are two main ways:

1. Resize input to the nearest feasible size.
2. Pad the input to the next larger feasible size.

I prefer (2) because (1) can cause small changes in the pixel level for all the pixels, leading to unnecessary blurriness. Note that we usually need to recover the original shape afterward in both methods.

My favorite code snippet for this task (symmetric padding for height/width):

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

def pad_to(x, stride):
    h, w = x.shape[-2:]

    if h % stride > 0:
        new_h = h + stride - h % stride
    else:
        new_h = h
    if w % stride > 0:
        new_w = w + stride - w % stride
    else:
        new_w = w
    lh, uh = int((new_h-h) / 2), int(new_h-h) - int((new_h-h) / 2)
    lw, uw = int((new_w-w) / 2), int(new_w-w) - int((new_w-w) / 2)
    pads = (lw, uw, lh, uh)

    # zero-padding by default.
    # See others at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.pad
    out = F.pad(x, pads, "constant", 0)

    return out, pads

def unpad(x, pad):
    if pad[2]+pad[3] > 0:
        x = x[:,:,pad[2]:-pad[3],:]
    if pad[0]+pad[1] > 0:
        x = x[:,:,:,pad[0]:-pad[1]]
    return x
```

A test snippet:

```py
x = torch.zeros(4, 3, 1080, 1920) # Raw data
x_pad, pads = pad_to(x, 16) # Padded data, feed this to your network 
x_unpad = unpad(x_pad, pads) # Un-pad the network output to recover the original shape

print('Original: ', x.shape)
print('Padded: ', x_pad.shape)
print('Recovered: ', x_unpad.shape)
```

Output:

```py
Original:  torch.Size([4, 3, 1080, 1920])
Padded:  torch.Size([4, 3, 1088, 1920])
Recovered:  torch.Size([4, 3, 1080, 1920])
```

Reference: https://github.com/seoungwugoh/STM/blob/905f11492a6692dd0d0fa395881a8ec09b211a36/helpers.py#L33

Comment: Thanks! Padding seems to be a better option.